# Create a FileReference from a existing file under fileadmin

Tags: typo3

My idea is to use

to select a file and  then create a \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference from the file for storage in my extension.

I found a lot examples for file uploads, but I have no need upload a file, only to select and create a FileReference of it.

Could somebody provide me with a simple example?

It would be also helpful, if I could understand, how the data structure of the f:form.upload property file looks like?

Here my code example, which is missing:

```
<f:form action="update" name="recipe" object="{recipe}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <f:form.upload property="file" />
<f:form.submit value="Save" /> </f:form>
```

Comment: Here my code example, which is missing:

Comment: <f:form action="update" name="recipe" object="{recipe}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<f:render partial="Recipe/FormFields" arguments="{recipe:recipe}" />
 <f:form.submit value="Save" />
</f:form>

Comment: <f:form action="update" name="recipe" object="{recipe}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <f:form.upload property="file" />
  <f:form.submit value="Save" />
</f:form>

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method in a recent TYPO3 7.5.15 project. I created a custom FileReference model

The model:

```
namespace Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Model;

class FileReference extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\AbstractFileFolder {

/**
 * Uid of the referenced sys_file. Needed for extbase to serialize the
 * reference correctly.
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $uidLocal;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $tablenames = 'yourTableName';

/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceInterface $originalResource
 */
public function setOriginalResource(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceInterface $originalResource) {
    $this->originalResource = $originalResource;
    $this->uidLocal         = (int)$originalResource->getUid();
}

/**
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference
 */
public function getOriginalResource() {
    if($this->originalResource === NULL) {
        $this->originalResource = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance()->getFileReferenceObject(
            $this->getUid()
        );
    }

    return $this->originalResource;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTablenames() {
    return $this->tablenames;
}

/**
 * @param string $tablenames
 */
public function setTablenames($tablenames) {
    $this->tablenames = $tablenames;
}
```

}

Create a new FileReference in the controller by calling

```
$fileReference = $this->_uploadFalFile($fileName, $fileRelativePath, $newFileAbsolutePath . $newFileFileName);
```

Using the method:

```
 /**
 * @param $fileName
 * @param $target
 * @param $targetFilePath
 *
 * @return \Ventor\ExtKey\Domain\Model\FileReference
 */
protected function _uploadFalFile($fileName ,$target, $targetFilePath) {
    $storageRepository = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\StorageRepository');
    $newFileReference = new \Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Model\FileReference();
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceStorage $storage */
    $storage = $storageRepository->findByUid(1);

    $saveFolder = $storage->getFolder($target);
    $fileObject = $storage->addFile($targetFilePath, $saveFolder, $fileName);
    $newFileReference->setOriginalResource($fileObject);

    return $newFileReference;
}
```

The used storage uid is dependent on the storages you have configured in your setup. 1 will be the auto created fileadmin. But you can easily create a new storage in the TYPO3 backend and use the uid for that storage to to store your files. Just change the line

```
$storage = $storageRepository->findByUid(1);
```

to what ever fits your needs or make the storage uid a variable comming from the configuration.